# How does Xcode's jump to (symbol) work?

Tags: xcode4

The keyboard shortcut to jump to a particular line in Xcode is Cmd+L

[image]

Typing in line number easily works, but what is the "symbol" in "Type Line Number or Symbol"? I tried typing selector names, variable names, nothing seems to work. Anybody knows what the "symbol" here is referring to and how to use it?

Comment: Have you installed any versions of Xcode greater than 4.2? I'm seeing the same problem as you and think it may be related.

Comment: Nope 4.2 is the only one i have

Comment: Confirmed it is happening on 4.3 as well. Did it use to allow you to jump to a variable name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this feature is not working and will not, ever. In the upcoming Xcode 4.5 you will see just "Type Line Number" without the "or Symbol" part.

This very same question has been filed to Apple, but without answers.

Comment: I am using both 4.3.3 and 4.5.  I see that you are correct.  Here's the 50 plus an up-vote.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the only thing this does is jump by line number within the file.  The same question can be found in the apple forums, unanswered as well.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a loot at the same function in Xcode 3.2 should make it rather easy to understand:
[image]

The *'symbol'* in *'type in line number or symbol'* should thus probably mean *'symbol number n'*. E.g. typing 24 will take you to the 24th symbol (character) in the code.
As I don't have the newest Xcode I can't test to confirm this myself but I doubt they changed the functionality.